# Restricted Permissions

Tags: permissions, tableau-api

So I'm using Tableau 10 and Tableau server. I don't have direct control over the server side of things. But I have full control over the tableau dashboard.

**My Issue:**

Users need to download the data from workbooks. When they go to one particular workbook the option to download the data is not available:

[image: download options]

They can however download it using the tool tips - but to download the entire data set in one go, they'd need to use the option button above.

**Tableau server settings:**

These look like they are fine. I also have another workbook in this area and that one does not experience this problem.

[image: permissions]

I am "Publisher" and my boss is "Owner" - she can see it but I can't. All of this suggests it's a workbook setting?! But where?!?

Users need to download the data from workbooks. When they go to one particular workbook the option to download the data is not avaliable:

They can however download it using the tool tips - but to download the entire data set in one go, they'd need to use the option button above.

Tableau server settings:
These look like they are fine. I also have another workbook in this area and that one does not experience this problem.

I am "Publisher" and my boss is "Owner" - she can see it but I can't. All of this suggests it's a workbook setting?! But where?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a user clicks into a sheet of your dashboard, the Data or Crosstab selections of the Download button will be activated. It is greyed out on dashboards because there could be multiple sheets.

One trick is to make a dedicated download sheet and upload it with the rest of your dashboard. If you upload just a sheet, then all selections on the Download button are available without the user needing to click into anything.

Answer (score 0):

On a published dashboard, if you click on a worksheet on the dashboard, the download links become available. This will avoid the need to upload the worksheet separately.